# Should I make delegate of custom cell as a weakly referenced proprety?

Tags: swift, delegates, retain-cycle

**ViewController Code**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    deinit {
        print("ViewController deinitialised")
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func didTapBlue() {

    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, CustomCellDelegate {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as! CustomCell
        cell.delegate =  self
        cell.textLabel!.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }

    func buttonTapped() {
        print("Button tapped")
    }
}
```

**CustomCell Code**

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    deinit {
        print("Cell deinitialised")
    }

    var delegate: CustomCellDelegate! //When protocol Type is A
    // weak prefix when protocol Type is B
    // weak var delegate: CustomCellDelegate!

    @IBAction func buttonClickAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let del = self.delegate {
            del.buttonTapped()
        }
    }
}
```

**Protocol Type A**

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate{
    func buttonTapped()
}
```

**Protocol Type B**

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {
    func buttonTapped()
}
```

I am confused about what is the appropriate way to implement delegate pattern for passing message between Cell And ViewController. I know that if two objects hold each other's reference strongly, there will be a retain cycle and they won't get deallocated in the application lifetime.

In the above code, ViewController doesn't seem to hold reference of Cell. Hence I think it doesn't matter if I use protocol of type A and keep the strong reference of ViewController in cell.

But will my code be any safer if I declare the delegate property as a weakly referenced property? What are the implications of it?

**Update:**

Turns out that even if the ViewController is not holding direct reference of cell & even if TableView's reference is weak, ViewController is somehow holding strong reference to the cells. When I follow Method A, that is without declaring the delegate to be of weak reference. The deinit methods in Cell and ViewController never gets called. I checked in instruments too. The persistent retain count keeps increasing if I don't declare delegate as weak.

[image]

**Now the big question is how is ViewController holding strong reference to the cells?**

Comment: I think the real questions are a step before the cells: what is having an @IBOutlet with a strong reference? And if it's the ViewController how does it manage the retain cycle internally?

Comment: Updated with the full ViewController Code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Deinitialization Process:**

When the view controller is popped out. 
Then deinit method is  called.

Then only all the other references that view controller is holding is cleared.

Parents deinit triggers, child's deinit triggers then after all the deinit is traversed through then deallocation of parent is done finally at last.

If any of the child is strongly referencing the parent. The deinit of parent never gets called and all the deinitialization process halts. In our case, since cell is retaining view controller strongly. The deinit method of ViewController never gets called. Hence The retain cycle. 
Here is great explanation for [retain cycle.](http://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things going on there.

1. Making every ViewController conform to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource is needless since you already have UITableViewController and you'll probably need to override those methods anyway. You would be duplicating code at some point in your development lifecycle.
2. delegates always need to be a weak reference to avoid retain cycles.

Comment: Also note that since `buttonTapped` doesn't pass self, it is not easy to know which button was tapped.

Comment: @MatthewSeaman You're right. It would be hard to tell, but again... he would probably need to override the whole implementation anyway.

Comment: Code I showed here was for the demonstration purpose only. Please see the above updates.

Comment: Apparently the tableView is holded with a strong reference to the ViewController regardless the @IBOutlet being a weak reference. This is very interesting.